# How to create a file for use in c?

Tags: c, file

I have a program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
// ne menuvaj ovde
void wtf() {
    FILE *f = fopen("text.txt", "w");
    char c;
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        fputc(c, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
int main() {
    wtf();
    FILE *vlezna;
    vlezna=fopen("text.txt","r");

    float words=0,lines=0,average=0;
    int counter=0;
    char ch;
    while((ch=fgetc(vlezna))!=EOF)
    {
        if(ch==' ')
            words++;
        if(ch=='\n');
        {
            words++;lines++;
        }
    }
    average=words/lines;
    printf("%f",average);
    fclose(vlezna);
    vlezna=fopen("text.txt","r");
    while((ch=fgetc(vlezna))!=EOF)
    {   words=0;
        if(ch==' ')
            words++;
            if(ch=='\n')
            {
                words++;
                if(words<average) counter++;
            }
    }
    fclose(vlezna);
    printf("%d",counter);
}
```

So i presume the first function writes to the file. But i guess the file should be created first, and i don't know how(except with right click new text document).
Also i didn't know how to return the pointer at the beginning of the file so i closed it and opened it again presuming that that will return the pointer at the beginning?

Comment: Maybe i can create a txt file with right click but i guess i still need to include it?

Comment: fyi, it's usually a good idea to use only english in your sourcecode files, especially for anything that's not a comment (and even those are usually better in english).

Comment: Have you read the manpage for `fopen()`?  It explains what that `"w"` does in some detail.

Comment: This is your fourth question in under 24 hours, and it's poorly constructed, worded and researched. Please spend some more time *reading* on StackOverflow to get a better feeling for how this site works and which questions get useful answers, and perhaps get a good text book on C before jumping into the questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fopen` create the file if it does not exist if option is `"w"`.
Read the documentation here : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fopen/

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to create. For the man page of `fopen`:

```
``w''   Truncate to zero length or create text file for writing.  The stream is positioned at the
        beginning of the file.
```

To set the file pointer use `fseek`. However, to read **and** write you need different open flags.